# Saving CSV in MS access using VBA based on response from API

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, firebase-realtime-database

I am calling an API (firebase as backend) and in response I get the below data

```
{
  "-KLk7i27KUizlqMEnua2": true,
  "-KLk9uAth59pyDImwjtu": true,
  "-KLszfh9xdYNqa5LcEvE": true,
  "-KLt-bCr5Fw9wCIFz9Mc": true
}
```

I am replacing the `{` and `}` and then using the data as CSV.

I want to save the data in `tblStudents` under column `studentID`

Which function / method should be used to save this data in Tables which I am receiving from API.

Any help will be appreciated. Or guide me to relevant page.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Json modules from [VBA.CVRAPI](https://github.com/CactusData/VBA.CVRAPI.git) you can modify these functions to read the Json string *as is*, and directly add the data to your recordset:

```
Public Sub TestJsonResponseText()

    Dim ResponseText As String

    ' For testing only.
    ResponseText = _
        "{" & _
        """-KLk7i27KUizlqMEnua2"": true," & _
        """-KLk9uAth59pyDImwjtu"": true," & _
        """-KLszfh9xdYNqa5LcEvE"": true," & _
        """-KLt-bCr5Fw9wCIFz9Mc"": true" & _
        "}"

    Dim DataCollection      As Collection
    If ResponseText <> "" Then
        Set DataCollection = CollectJson(ResponseText)
    End If

    Call ListFieldNames(DataCollection)

    Set DataCollection = Nothing

End Sub


Public Sub ListFieldNames( _
    ByVal DataCollection As Collection)

    On Error GoTo Err_ListFieldNames

    Dim Index               As Long

    For Index = 1 To DataCollection.Count
        If VarType(DataCollection(Index)(CollectionItem.Data)) = vbObject Then
            Debug.Print "rs.OpenRecordset"
            Call ListFieldNames(DataCollection(Index)(CollectionItem.Data))
            Debug.Print "rs.Close"
        Else
            Debug.Print , "AddNew"
            Debug.Print , DataCollection(Index)(CollectionItem.Name), DataCollection(Index)(CollectionItem.Data)
            Debug.Print , "Update"
        End If
    Next

Exit_ListFieldNames:
    Exit Sub

Err_ListFieldNames:
    Debug.Print "Error" & Str(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ListFieldNames

End Sub
```

Of course, replace the `Debug.Print` lines with code to handle your recordset.

For testing, the function *TestJsonResponseText* above returns:

```
rs.OpenRecordset
              AddNew
              -KLk7i27KUizlqMEnua2        True
              Update
              AddNew
              -KLk9uAth59pyDImwjtu        True
              Update
              AddNew
              -KLszfh9xdYNqa5LcEvE        True
              Update
              AddNew
              -KLt-bCr5Fw9wCIFz9Mc        True
              Update
rs.Close
```

Comment: There are few `.bas` files in the github. Which `.bas` file should I import to test this out?

Comment: It's the _Json*.bas_ files. The _JsonTest.bas_ is the one to modify (as used above) or to replace with your own code.

Comment: When I print `DataCollection(Index)(CollectionItem.Name)` to my console, I am getting just `root`. I also tried adding `1` instead of `index`

Comment: When I implemented exactly as your example. I get `Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set`

Comment: I don't know. It worked here. Where do you see that error?

Comment: Have in mind that `ListFieldNames` is called _recursively_.